# Ajustar tiempos de medias horas en momentum

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy tratando de hacer una agenda y para sacar las horas utilizo Momentum, por ejemplo, si la hora actual son las 23:01 quiero que el primero horario que aparezca sea 23:30, luego 24:00, 24:30, etc. O si son 14:35 que aparezca desde 15:00 y así cada media hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que esto te sirva, la lógica que necesitas se basa en analizar los minutos actuales, si son mayores 30 se deberá sumar una hora al momento actual y setear a los minutos en cero, de lo contrario se deberán setear los minutos a 30 y la hora continua siendo la misma. Todo esto lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma, puedes omitir la función de format si no deseas mantener el format.

```
function getFormatedHour(hour) {
  let minutes = hour.minutes();

  if (minutes > 30) {
    hour.add('hour', 1).set('minute', 0);
  } else {
    hour.set('minute', 30);
  }

  return hour.format('LT'); 
}

let testHours = [
  moment().set({ hours: 2, minutes: 1}),
  moment().set({ hours: 2, minutes: 15}),
  moment().set({ hours: 2, minutes: 59}),
  moment().set({ hours: 23, minutes: 48})
];


testHours.forEach(hour => console.log(getFormatedHour(hour)));
```